# WPF autoresize a label

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<Label Content="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay, Path=ViewTitle}" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,69,48,0" Name="labelScreenTitle" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding}" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="15" />
```

Here is the xaml for the label.  ViewTitle has the text value I need to display.  Since this can vary in length from screen to screen, I need this to be Auto.  I am getting the following errors:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'MicroLabQuant.ViewModels.MainViewModel' and 'System.Double'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=; DataItem='MainViewModel' (HashCode=9080996); target element is 'Label' (Name='labelScreenTitle'); target property is 'Width' (type 'Double')
```

System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='MicroLabQuant.ViewModels.MainViewModel' BindingExpression:Path=; DataItem='MainViewModel' (HashCode=9080996); target element is 'Label' (Name='labelScreenTitle'); target property is 'Width' (type 'Double')

I understand it wants a conversion because we're trying to set the width, which is a double.  But how do you do that with a Converter?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just don't set the `Width` property at all.

Comment: Why do you even want to bind the width in this scenario? If you remove the width property on your label, it should autoresize based on the content. You might want to set the maxwidth instead to keep to a certain max size.

Comment: You set Mode=OneWay which means that Text is retrieved only from ViewTitle and no change in Label.Content is sent back to source and then you set UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to update source(ViewTitle). It does not make sense. Width="{Binding}" means you are binding to current DataContext so it is supposed to be property with type of Double, but first you did a binding to Content="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay, Path=ViewTitle}" which one i guess is some kind of text property. You need to get familiar with binding. By the way, Label is meant for displaying.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right.  I am pretty new to wpf and binding.  I like your explanation and I'm glad I posted this question so that I could get some ancillary help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the Width binding... your label will size according to the content automatically by default.

```
<Label Content="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay, Path=ViewTitle}" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,69,48,0" Name="labelScreenTitle" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="15" />
```

Comment: I have just noticed that you dont seem to accept answers to any of your questions... You need to click the tick located just to the left of the answer that you feel solved your issue. This encourages people to answer more of your questions and also rewards those who took the time to help you. Please try and get into a habit of this.

Comment: Should have known about the tick mark.  I will utilize it going forward.